# Get size of a group knowing its grouper id in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, size

In the following snippet, `data` is a `pandas.DataFrame` and `indices` is a set of columns of the `data`. After grouping the data with `groupby`, I am interested in the ids of the groups, but only those with a size greater than a threshold (say: 3).

```py
group_ids=data.groupby(list(data.columns[list(indices)])).grouper.group_info[0]
```

Now, how can I find which group has a size greater than or equal 3 knowing the id of the group? I only want ids of groups with a certain size.

```
#TODO: filter out ids from group_ids which correspond to groups with sizes < 3
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One way is to use the [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) method of the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
g = data.groupby(...)
size = g.size()
size[size > 3]
```

For example, here there is only one group of size > 1:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1,6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  1  6 

In [13]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [14]: size = g.size()

In [15]: size[size > 1]
Out[15]:
A
1    2
dtype: int64
```

If you were interested in just restricting the DataFrame to those in large groups you could use the [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) method:

```
In [21]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[21]:
   A  B
0  1  2
2  1  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `value_counts()` here to get size of groups.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'L1': list('ZXYXYXY'), 'L2': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]})


   L1  L2
0   Z   1
1   X   0
2   Y   1
3   X   0
4   Y   0
5   X   0
6   Y   1
```

The basic idea is to get the size of each group and filter the groupers (`grp` below) that correspond are at least size 3.

```py
grp = 'L1'
size = df.value_counts(grp)
size.index[size>=3]             # Index(['X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name='L1')
```

---

If we want to use the `group_ids`, then `numpy.unique()` could be useful. The basic idea is to count the unique grouper ids and filter the ones that have at least 3 values. This will give the grouper ids that are at least of size 3.

If we want to look at the group keys that correspond to these values, we can use these indices to filter the `group_keys_seq` attribute, which is equal to the index filtered using `value_counts()` above.<sup>1</sup>

```py
grp = 'L1'
g = df.groupby(grp).grouper
# count unique grouper ids
u, c = np.unique(g.group_info[0], return_counts=True)
idx = u[c >= 3]                 # array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
g.group_keys_seq[idx]           # Index(['X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name='L1')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If the `groupby` is done on multiple columns, then `group_keys_seq` returns a list of tuples and it can't be indexed like `g.group_keys_seq[idx]`. In that case, use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(g.group_keys_seq)[idx]` instead.