# Resample and aggregating dataframe by date and city

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to resample a dataframe by date and creating a column based on the aggregate sum of city
    df:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+
| booking_date    |  Cities           |  province  | 
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Depok       | Jawa Barat |    
|  15-12-17       |  Bogor            | Jawa Barat |      
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Depok       | Jawa Barat |     
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Bandung     | Jawa Barat |    
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Bandung     | Jawa Barat |   
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+
```

The output may looks like this:

```
df:

+-----------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| booking_date    |  Cities           |  province  |  Count     | 
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Depok       | Jawa Barat |  2         |
|  15-12-17       |  Bogor            | Jawa Barat |  1         |
|  15-12-17       |  Kota Bandung     | Jawa Barat |  2         | 
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and `name` parameter:

```
df = df.groupby(['booking_date','Cities','province']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Comment: dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945247/pandas-groupby-get-size-of-a-group-knowing-its-id-from-grouper-group-info0)?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that came to my mind was the same as @jezrael's one. However, another could be the one combining [`pandas.DataFrame.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html),  [`pandas.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [`pandas.Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

The code is following.

```
>>> df = df\
...     .assign(Count = df['Cities'].map(df['Cities'].value_counts()))\
...     .drop_duplicates()
>>> print(df)
  booking_date        Cities    province  Count
0     15-12-17    Kota Depok  Jawa Barat      2
1     15-12-17         Bogor  Jawa Barat      1
3     15-12-17  Kota Bandung  Jawa Barat      2
```