# How to compare repeated values ​of the same column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using this dataset to solve a problem ->https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction.

I used this code to see repeated values in the column "id": `pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("id") if len(g) > 1)` and the output is this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRli7.jpg)

what i'm want to do is to compare repeated values, e.g: id 1000102 appear two times, that means it was sold more than once in the range. What I would like to do is take these two entries and compare the sale value in the "price" column to find the biggest variances, but with all the entries. For example sorting from highest to lowest variation.

Comment: Please show the code as test, not images. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/14627505), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What would you like your output to be? The full dataframe with [values in groups sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27842613/14627505)? Or the maximum values (or [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51074911/14627505)) of each group ([that has length >1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17945528/14627505))? Please provide an example output that you're after

Comment: @IsmaelPauchner, no worries - that is exactly why we are giving you advice and not downvoting - with the hope that you learn :)

Comment: Sorry for the errors, it's my first post. @VladimirFokow As I would like to know if the houses made a profit or loss being sold more than once in the period, what I would like is to make the id's second appearance - its first appearance. For example: with id 1000102, row 2497 in the price column (second appearance) with a value of 300000.0 - row 2496 (first appearance) with a value of 280000.0. The output would be 20000.0.

Comment: @DialFrost[link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JdxD81fohYT4n6lLI9m7Z3RZLJmU850M?usp=sharing) here's the code that I used.

Comment: How do you want [rows with 'id' 17602-17604](https://imgur.com/a/0CrpKsv) be handled? This is the only group with 3 elements in it.  Also: generally, do you want to get just this difference for each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groups by `'id'`: from the LAST element subtract the FIRST one. This will be the `diff` value that corresponds to the `'id'` of the group.

```py
diffs = df_2.groupby('id')['price'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0] )
diffs.name = 'diff'
```

You can aggregate with any function here! For example: `lambda x: x.max() - x.min()`.

If you'd like to join the `diffs` Series as a column to the `df`:

```py
df.iloc[:, :3].merge(diffs, left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

---

#### Other

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584371/14627505) provides a better version of leaving only groups with more than 1 element:

```py
df_2 = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```